# disable clicking of a divs element

Tags: jquery

I have div that goes in to an edit mode... the div contains buttons, links++. In edit mode i want to disable all of these, and enable them when i exit edit mode.

Ive tried

```
$("#container").children().disableSelection();
```

but it does not work :-(

Comment: This may useful: http://stackoverflow.com/a/18983026/1830909

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Edit mode enter:

```
$("#container").children().bind('click', function(){ return false; });
```

Edit mode exit:

```
$("#container").children().unbind('click');
```

Comment: This should work. Although I would save the function as a variable so you can pass it to the unbind. You might not want to unbind all click events.

Answer (score 2):

Give all elements that you want to prevent clicking a class of "noclick", then when in edit mode:

```
$(".noclick").click(function(e) {
    if(editMode) {
        e.preventDefault();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

you use below that will help you:

$("#container").hide();

and when exit edit mode do:
$("#container").show();

Answer (score 0):

css:

`.dis{pointer-events:none}`

Jquery:

`$("#container").addClass("dis"); //disables`

`$("#container").removeClass("dis"); //enables`