# How to disable and then enable onclick event on <div> with javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

Following is the code which i am trying

```
document.getElementById("id").disabled = true;
```

Comment: Need more context, I think.

Comment: can you please provide a fiddle (jsfiddle.net) to share the html and javascript you are running?!

Comment: Please post relevant html and explain what you are trying to disable.  Divs have no disabled property.

Comment: can you put your html markup here?

Answer (score 128, accepted):

You can use the CSS property `pointer-events` to disable the click event on any element:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/pointer-events

```
// To disable:    
document.getElementById('id').style.pointerEvents = 'none';
// To re-enable:
document.getElementById('id').style.pointerEvents = 'auto'; 
// Use '' if you want to allow CSS rules to set the value
```

Here is a JsBin: http://jsbin.com/oyAhuRI/1/edit

Comment: Thanks its Working.To enable document.getElementById('id').style.pointerEvents = 'visible';

Comment: To re-enable you should use the value `'auto'`. The value `'visible'` is invalid for `pointer-events` so the browser ignores it and sets `'auto'` by default.

Comment: This does not work in IE10. The link stay clickable.

Comment: For jquery, `$('#id').css('pointer-events', 'none');`

Answer (score 21):

I'm confused by your question, seems to me that the question title and body are asking different things. If you want to disable/enable a click event on a div simply do:

```
$("#id").on('click', function(){ //enables click event
    //do your thing here
});

$("#id").off('click'); //disables click event
```

If you want to disable a div, use the following code:

```
$("#id").attr('disabled','disabled');
```

Hope this helps.

edit:
oops, didn't see the other bind/unbind answer. Sorry. Those methods are also correct, though they've been deprecated in jQuery 1.7, and replaced by on()/off()

Comment: The `off()` method seems to not be working as you showed, perhaps it was replaced in jQuery 1.11?

Comment: The `on()` and `off()` is working just fine for me and I'm using jQuery 3.2.1. Nice find @Paraphiliac Ostrich

Answer (score 3):

To enable use [`bind()`](http://api.jquery.com/bind/) method

```
$("#id").bind("click",eventhandler);
```

call this handler

```
 function  eventhandler(){
      alert("Bind click")
    }
```

To disable click use[`unbind()`](http://api.jquery.com/unbind/)

```
$("#id").unbind("click");
```

Answer (score 1):

You can disable the event by applying following code:

with `.attr()` API

```
$('#your_id').attr("disabled", "disabled");
```

or with `.prop()` API

```
$('#your_id').prop('disabled', true);
```

Comment: I have tried your code but it is not working

Comment: Which element you are trying to disable?

Comment: <div> element in the html.basically i am trying to disable onclick event in <div>

Comment: You can also use with .preventDefault() API:  '$('#your_id').click(function(e) { e.preventDefault(); return false; });'

Answer (score 0):

First of all this is JavaScript and not C#

Then you cannot disable a div because it normally has no functionality. To disable a click event, you simply have to remove the event from the dom object. (bind and unbind)...

Comment: $("#id").unbind(); i am using following code but it is not working.please help

Comment: post your code snipet, ideally create a jsfiddle so that it is easier to find out what your issue is