# Can i on off element event without know the function inside event

Tags: jquery

Is this posible to on off the event inside element without know the function inside event using jquery??

Thanks

Comment: where is your code? Without code we can't help you.

Comment: Yes, it's possible! Did you try it!

Comment: Show the code you have tried so far.

Comment: What is issue, share code how someone will help you with this

Comment: please check the similar answer

[Block Event][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18982642/how-to-disable-and-then-enable-onclick-event-on-div-with-javascript

Answer (score 0):

Please try `Off` method in jquery
please refer [jQuery DOCS](http://api.jquery.com/off/)

Comment: Hi can you provide an example to make your answer more relevant?

Comment: _[Your answer is in another castle: when is an answer not an answer?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/225370/your-answer-is-in-another-castle-when-is-an-answer-not-an-answer)_

Answer (score 0):

```
<form id="CreateForm" method="post">
        <div class="editor-label">
            <label for="Customer_FirstName">FirstName</label>
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            <input class="text-box single-line" id="Customer_FirstName" name="Customer.FirstName" type="text" value="" />
            <span class="field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-for="Customer.FirstName" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
        </div>
        <div class="editor-label">
            <label for="Customer_LastName">LastName</label>
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            <input class="text-box single-line" id="Customer_LastName" name="Customer.LastName" type="text" value="" />
            <span class="field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-for="Customer.LastName" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
        </div>
        <p>
            <input type="button" value="Create" />
            <input type="button" value="ForceValidate" />
            <button type="button" id="Disable" >Disable</button>
        </p>
    </form>
```

Jquery

```
$(document).ready(function () {
     $("input[type='button']").click(function () {
        alert("test");

    });
    $("#Disable").click(function () {
        $("input[type='button']").off("click");
    });

});
```

Please check the above demo which is used `off` for removing an event from input type button

Comment: how i off and on again if i don't know what function isset at click event

Comment: I have done an example on and off an event https://jsfiddle.net/f9k7xp5s/ Please check let me know if it satisfies you

Comment: may the simple is... i have a event that is hidden (we don't know what function is set in this event).. how i got the function before i off the event, and i can on this event with same function on other situation??