# Clickable divs based on current date

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, clickable

I have a page with several divs, containing image with link, which I want to become from unclickable to clickable based on the date.
For example - I have 5 divs for 5 days (01.03.2016, 02.03.2016, 03.03.2016, 04.03.2016, 05.03.2016). Inside these divs I have image with link.

on 01.03.2016 - only div 1 to be clickable, all others not

on 02.03.2016 - only div1 and div2 to be clickable, all other not
and etc...

on 05.03.2016 - all five divs to be clickable

Thank you in advance

Comment: Have you tried anything ?

Comment: can be duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18982642/how-to-disable-and-then-enable-onclick-event-on-div-with-javascript

Comment: I was using CSS property pointer-events, but can figure out how to control it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
var divs = document.getElementsByClassName("date");

for (i = 0 ; i < divs.length ; i++) {
  divs[i].style.pointerEvents = 'none';
}

for (i = 0 ; i < divs.length ; i++) {  
  var divDate = divs[i].id.split('.');
  var date = new Date(divDate[2], divDate[1] - 1, divDate[0]);
  
  if (date <= new Date()) {
    divs[i].style.pointerEvents = 'auto';
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="date" id="01.03.2016">01.03.2016 <a href="ihttp://google.com"><img src="images/image1.jpg" alt="Google Image" width="138" height="138" class="img_rounded" /></a></div>
<div class="date" id="02.03.2016">02.03.2016 <a href="ihttp://google.com"><img src="images/image1.jpg" alt="Google Image" width="138" height="138" class="img_rounded" /></a></div>
<div class="date" id="03.03.2016">03.03.2016 <a href="ihttp://google.com"><img src="images/image1.jpg" alt="Google Image" width="138" height="138" class="img_rounded" /></a></div>
<div class="date" id="04.03.2016">04.03.2016 <a href="ihttp://google.com"><img src="images/image1.jpg" alt="Google Image" width="138" height="138" class="img_rounded" /></a></div>
<div class="date" id="09.03.2016">09.03.2016 <a href="ihttp://google.com"><img src="images/image1.jpg" alt="Google Image" width="138" height="138" class="img_rounded" /></a></div>
```

Comment: Hi @Munawir
your code is working here when I run code snippet, but when I copy and paste into my local machine, it doesn't work? Do you know why ?

Answer (score 0):

I would use date comparison. Perhaps something like that:

**HTML**

```
<div class="date">01.03.2016</div>
<div class="date">02.03.2016</div>
<div class="date">03.03.2016</div>
<div class="date">04.03.2016</div>
<div class="date">05.03.2016</div>
```

**JavaScript:**

```
var elms = document.getElementsByClassName("date");
for (var i = 0 ; i < elms.length ; i++)
{
   var el = elms[i];
   var dmy = el.innerHTML.split('.');
   var date = new Date(dmy[2], dmy[1] - 1, dmy[0]);
   if (date <= new Date()) {
      el.style.backgroundColor = "yellow";
      el.onclick = function () {
         alert("you clicked on " + this.innerHTML)        
      };
   }
}
```

**DEMO**
Here's a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/3oLeq8su/)

Comment: Thanks a lot, I think it should help :)
I will wait and for other suggestions

Comment: Hi @remdevtec
I tried your code and it's working as you show on demo, but when I have a link inside the div - it doesn't work
Here is the example:

`<div class="date">05.03.2016 
<a href="ihttp://google.com">
<img src="images/image1.jpg" alt="Google Image" width="138" height="138" class="img_rounded" />
</a>
</div>`

Can you give me advice how to fix it ?

Comment: Hi @remdevtec,
yes something like you last answer, but in the demo, the upcoming dates/divs are clickable and the must be not clickable

Comment: Do you want the text of date dd.mm.yyyy to be clickable/non-clickable along with the `<a>` tag? Note that in the original demo the dates are all in the past so they are clickable. If you want to change the clickability condition just play with the `if (date <= new Date()) {` line.

Comment: Thanks @remdevtec,
I manage to solve it with your help and the other answers.

Answer (score 0):

> HTML

```
 <div class="date" id="First">01.03.2016</div>
 <div class="date all" id="Second">02.03.2016</div>
 <div class="date all three two"   id="Third">03.03.2016</div>
 <div class="date all three two one"   id="Fourth">04.03.2016</div>
 <div class="date all three two one zero"  id="Fifth">05.03.2016</div>
```

> In JQuery Disable the click

```
  $("#First").click(function(){
     $(".all ").off('click');
   }
  $("#Second").click(function(){
     $(".three ")off('click');
   }
  $("#Third").click(function(){
     $(".two")off('click');
   }
  $("#Fourth").click(function(){
     $(".one").off('click');
   }
  $("#Fifth").click(function(){
     $(".zero")off('click');
   }
```

> OR In JQuery Disable the div

```
  $("#First").click(function(){
     $(".date").removeAttr('disabled','disabled');
     $(".all ").attr('disabled','disabled');
   }
  $("#Second").click(function(){
     $(".date").removeAttr('disabled','disabled');
     $(".three ").attr('disabled','disabled');
   }
  $("#Third").click(function(){
     $(".date").removeAttr('disabled','disabled');
     $(".two").attr('disabled','disabled');
   }
  $("#Fourth").click(function(){
     $(".date").removeAttr('disabled','disabled');
     $(".one").attr('disabled','disabled');
   }
  $("#Fifth").click(function(){
     $(".date").removeAttr('disabled','disabled');
     $(".zero").attr('disabled','disabled');
   }
```