# Disabling the OnClick in a nested Div programmatically with Javascript/JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, disabled-input

I have a Javascript application which allows users to enable/disable controls at runtime. I have been successful in disabling/enabling nested inputs and buttons, but so far I have had no success in disabling an onclick event in a Div, so that the circled icon will not be selectable:

[image]

The generated HTML looks like:

```
<div id="56f81c3d-9666-4dab-8f35-d36e894f426f" class="field alert-success">
    <div class="field-name">By default I am disabled - Single Photo</div>
        <div id="56f81c3d-9666-4dab-8f35-d36e894f426fPhoto" class="clearfix" style="cursor: pointer; max-width: 100%; max-height: 100%;" onclick="ffffield.getFieldHandler('PhotoPicker').showPhotoCapture(this, '56f81c3d-9666-4dab-8f35-d36e894f426f');">
            <img class="pull-right" src="/MySite.Web/Content/device/images/chevronRight.png" style="width: 20px; position:relative; top: 7px;">
            <img class="pull-right" src="/MySite.Web/Content/device/images/photoPickerPlaceholder@2x.png" style="width: 40px; position:relative; top: -5px;">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>.
```

In this snippet, it is the "onclick" that I need to disable. I am not picky - it can be disabling the pointer or the onclick.

I have tried the following attempts to make this work:

```
$("#56f81c3d-9666-4dab-8f35-d36e894f426f").children().off('click');
```

and

```
$("#56f81c3d-9666-4dab-8f35-d36e894f426f input").prop("disabled", true);
```

and

```
$("#"#56f81c3d-9666-4dab-8f35-d36e894f426f input").attr("disabled", true);
```

and

```
$(""#56f81c3d-9666-4dab-8f35-d36e894f426f input").attr("disabled", "disabled");
```

based on some other stackoverflow questions.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18982642/how-to-disable-and-then-enable-onclick-event-on-div-with-javascript

Comment: `div[disabled] { pointerEvents : none; }`

Comment: @epascarello Thanks for the response.I tried the accepted answer on the stackflow above. What is the jquery way to set the disable the pointer?

Comment: use css() .....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.off()` can only disable event listeners that were added with `.on()` (or other jQuery methods, since they all call `.on()` internally). To remove an event listener that was added using the `onclick` attribute, you need to reassign the `onclick` property:

```
$("#56f81c3d-9666-4dab-8f35-d36e894f426f").children().prop('onclick', null);
```

Comment: That worked like a charm. How do I go about re-enabling it since the user can toggle it?

Comment: Save the old value in a variable.

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot save the last value since there can be hundreds of instances of this (unless I build a whole new construct). But I can regenerate the same method in place. How would that look in this instance?  $("#" + targetField.id).on('click', "ffffield.getFieldHandler('PhotoPicker').showPhotoCapture(this,'" + targetField.id + "Photo');");  Where targetField.id is #56f81c3d-9666-4dab-8f35-d36e894f426f?

Comment: Do you really need to remove the handlers? Why not just set a variable that the handler function checks before doing anything?

Comment: I can probably skip the handler removal - in fact I am wondering if disabling the pointer for the control wouldn't be better. As for a variable...I could, but then I need to build an array of flag indexed by the Id, since there can be hundreds of these fields. Just seems like an overkill just to disable a control.

Comment: I think the problem is that a `div` is not a control, so it doesn't support the `disabled` property.

Comment: I have read some posts about changing the style to eliminate the pointer itself for the DIV. But I am not positive it is possible either. Rather new to javascript and never was much of a CSS coder.

Comment: I'm not sure how that works. It sounds like it just makes the pointer invisible, but you can still click with it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
function disableDiv( div ) {
    div.addEventListener( "click", function ( event ) {
        event.stopPropagation();
    }, true );
}

// call the disable div handler
disableDiv( document.getElementById( "56f81c3d-9666-4dab-8f35-d36e894f426f" ) );
```