# How to disable clicking inside div

Tags: javascript, jquery

For many reasons I need to disable clicking on certain content within a `div` element. Due to clicking ads attacks, for example.
I still want it to be visible tho.

Consider the following snippet :-

```
<div class="ads">
something should be here, i do not want to be clicked
</div>
```

how to disable the abilities of left-clicking whithin that `div`?

Comment: FWIW, ads are typically written into iframes to prevent the host page from having access

Comment: check this out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5259191/disable-clicking-of-a-divs-element

Answer (score 205, accepted):

The CSS property that can be used is:

```
pointer-events:none
```

**!IMPORTANT**
Keep in mind that this property is not supported by Opera Mini and IE 10 and below (inclusive). Another solution is needed for these browsers.

**jQuery METHOD**
If you want to disable it via script and not CSS property, these can help you out:
If you're using jQuery versions 1.4.3+:

```
$('selector').click(false);
```

If not:

```
$('selector').click(function(){return false;});
```

- Referenced from :
  [jquery - disable click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4589964/jquery-disable-click)

---

You can **re-enable** clicks with **`pointer-events: auto;`** ([Documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/CSS/pointer-events))

Note that [`pointer-events`](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/CSS/pointer-events) overrides the [`cursor`](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_cursor) property, so if you want the cursor to be something other than the standard [image: cursor], your css should be place *after* `pointer-events`.

Comment: Oh you are my life saver! I did spend a lot of time try to find out how to prevent user from clicking on an item. Later on, "cursor event" phrase appeared in my head and I got your answer. Cool, isn't it?

Comment: Now it's supported by mobile Opera: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/pointer-events

Comment: I have a component that floating on another component, they aren't parent-child related, and I don't want the user to click on the above one. Your CSS method works like a charm.

Answer (score 52):

If you want it in pure CSS:

```
pointer-events:none;
```

Comment: what! this is totally awesome .. tested and works perfect, never know about that css property before .. thanks a lot

Comment: Please see my answer below as this is not a robust solution.

Comment: For me this is not a good solution. This disables not only click event, but also scroll and others ...

Comment: simple and precise way to do the stuff. Thank you very much :)

Comment: Works nicely, but seriously, what does this have to do with _styling_?! This shouldn't be a CSS property.

Answer (score 7):

Try this:

```
pointer-events:none
```

Adding above on the specified HTML element will prevents all click, state and cursor options.

http://jsfiddle.net/4hrpsrnp/

```
<div class="ads">
 <button id='noclick' onclick='clicked()'>Try</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 5):

If using function onclick DIV and then want to disable click it again you can use this :

```
for (var i=0;i<document.getElementsByClassName('ads').length;i++){
    document.getElementsByClassName('ads')[i].onclick = false;
}
```

Example : 
HTML

```
<div id='mybutton'>Click Me</div>
```

Javascript

```
document.getElementById('mybutton').onclick = function () {
    alert('You clicked');
    this.onclick = false;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use css

```
.ads{pointer-events:none}
```

or Using javascript prevent event

```
$("selector").click(function(event){
   event.preventDefault();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

How to disable clicking another div click until first one popup div close

[image: Image of the example]

```
 <p class="btn1">One</p>
 <div id="box1" class="popup">
 Test Popup Box One
 <span class="close">X</span>
 </div>

 <!-- Two -->
 <p class="btn2">Two</p>
 <div id="box2" class="popup">
 Test Popup Box Two
 <span class="close">X</span>
  </div>

<style>
.disabledbutton {
 pointer-events: none;
 }

.close {
cursor: pointer;
}

</style>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
//One
$(".btn1").click(function(){
  $("#box1").css('display','block');
  $(".btn2,.btn3").addClass("disabledbutton");

});
$(".close").click(function(){
  $("#box1").css('display','none');
  $(".btn2,.btn3").removeClass("disabledbutton");
});
</script>
```