# Disabling routerLink - Angular

Tags: javascript

I have a clickable `div` and I would like to disable it in some cases.

```
    <div id="div" routerLink="/url" class="module-dashboard"></div>
```

I have tried:

```
var div= <HTMLDivElement>document.getElementById("div");
div.disabled = true;
```

But "disabled" is not a property of `HTMLDivElement`

What I need is to avoid the `routerLink`.

Is it possible to do it?

Comment: Do you want to disable click on `div`?

Comment: do u have some sort of click event on that div?

Comment: Is there any reason why you are using `<HTMLDivElement>` ?

Comment: I have href on the div, so I want to disable the click on it

Comment: how do you bind the event? onclick or addEventListener

Comment: In pure CSS: pointer-events:none Found here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/28083939/8814529

Comment: we need more code about how you add the event and the div

Comment: You should rethink the way you are using elements. divs are layout elements and not links. If you still want to use it as links, encapsulate it in an anchor tag.

Comment: @MarioLópez you have just turned the question around!

Answer (score 1):

The `removeEventListener()` method removes an event handler that has been attached with the `addEventListener()` method.

```
var _el = document.getElementById("div");
_el.removeEventListener("click", eventHandler);
```

Here `eventHandler` is the function you attached on click using `addEventListener`. Anonymous function like `"element.removeEventListener("event", function(){ myScript })` will not work.

Comment: This applies ONLY if he attached the event handler with `addEventListener`. This wont work if he used `onclick` in the element.

Answer (score 0):

Try this. Click will work only once.

```js
var e = document.getElementById("button");
e.onclick = function() {
  this.onclick = null;
  console.log("disabled!");
};
```

```html
<div id="button">Clickable DIV</div>
```