# Angular2 disable click on div

Tags: html, angular, angular-template

I tried lots and search numbers of time but I didnt get any solution to disable click on div element. Already question has been asked but they are saying **not possible on divs** and I want to know only, is there any ways to disable div in **angular2**

```
<div>(click)="isDisabled ? $event.stopPropagation() : myClickHandler($event); isDisabled ? false : null"
   [class.isDisabled]="isDisabled"></div>
```

And the old answer not clearly about disabling divs and pointer-events:none is not supported in old version browser also it become editable from network tab

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to disable clicking inside div](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28083708/how-to-disable-clicking-inside-div)

Comment: How is `div` even `enabled`? You have to actually programmatically make clicks on div even do anything, what would you disable?

Comment: Yeh, I checked but the answer not supporting in  old browser

Comment: Could you post some of your code so we can see what you have tried?

Comment: @ritaj , I need to restrict divs to be clicked till my request has been completed

Comment: If the div is visible, the user can click on it. What is it, when the user clicks on the div, that you actually want to prevent?

Comment: but its visible, somehow I just need to be non clickable or further click not happen till the request get completed, is there any way or any solution or any other way

Comment: What happens when the user clicks on the div? What problem does it create?

Answer (score 13):

You can use css:

```
pointer-events:none
```

Or maybe could do something like:

```
<div (click)="false; $event.stopPropagation();"> </div>
```

There are several ways of preventing a click, depends on what you need

Comment: I just need to restrict the click event on divs thats it, but without css

Answer (score 2):

The straightforward answer here will be just not to render the function if the element should be disabled. Something like this:

```
<div (click)="shouldBeDisabled ? null : callYourFunctionHere()"></div>
```

But a better solution will be to put this condition into your function itself

HTML

```
<div (click)="callYourFunctionHere()"></div>
```

TS

```
const callYourFunctionHere = () => {
  if (this.shouldBeDisabled) return
  
  //if statement above is false your general logic will be rendered
}
```