# Prevent all clicks on embedded element

Tags: html, css

I use embedded tweets in my website, however, I would like to prevent any type of user interaction with these embedded tweets other than showing them to my users. Following the advise [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28083708/how-to-disable-clicking-inside-div), I wrapped the embed code inside a `<div>` element with the CSS property `pointer-events:none`, as in the example below, nevertheless, the embedded tweet in the  remains clickable. Any ideas how to mask it with an invisible NON-CLICKABLE layer?

```html
<div class="right" style="display:inline-block;float:left;pointer-events:none;z-index:2">
  <blockquote class="twitter-tweet">
    <p lang="en" dir="ltr">Or hey, ya know, just relax and have fun. <a href="https://twitter.com/U53iZEL9O9">https://twitter.com/U53iZEL9O9</a></p>&mdash; Meg Turney (@megturney) <a href="https://twitter.com/megturney/status/1230141853246402560?ref_src=twsrc%5Etfw">February 19, 2020</a></blockquote>
  <script async src="https://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
</div>
```

Comment: There are other answers on the linked question with advice on JavaScript to add...

Comment: indeed but those answers are fro IE and Opera. My problem is uniquely with Chrome

Comment: The answers are not specific to any browser. And indeed, the answers suggest the same thing as the answer given to this question.

Comment: Unless I'm missing something the code above works

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you wrote actually works well, and Chrome doesn't send click events to it. But we can add an `eventListener` to override anything that might be attached to it, and prevent the event from propagating with `event.stopPropagation()`. I added some CSS to disable text highlighting/selection as well.

It's a little hard to demonstrate an event is *not* firing, but you can see the console won't log the `"Uh oh, I got clicked"` message even if you click around.

```js
document.querySelectorAll(".unclickable").forEach(
  element => element.addEventListener("click",
    event => {
      event.preventDefault();
      return event.stopPropagation();
    }
  )
);
```

```css
.unclickable * {
  -webkit-touch-callout: none; /* iOS Safari */
    -webkit-user-select: none; /* Safari */
     -khtml-user-select: none; /* Konqueror HTML */
       -moz-user-select: none; /* Old versions of Firefox */
        -ms-user-select: none; /* Internet Explorer/Edge */
            user-select: none; /* Non-prefixed version, currently
                                  supported by Chrome, Opera and Firefox */
}
```

```html
<div onclick="console.log('Uh oh, I got clicked')" class="unclickable right" style="display:inline-block;float:left;pointer-events:none;z-index:2">
  <blockquote class="twitter-tweet">
    <p lang="en" dir="ltr">Or hey, ya know, just relax and have fun. <a href="https://twitter.com/U53iZEL9O9">https://twitter.com/U53iZEL9O9</a></p>&mdash; Meg Turney (@megturney) <a href="https://twitter.com/megturney/status/1230141853246402560?ref_src=twsrc%5Etfw">February 19, 2020</a></blockquote>
  <script async src="https://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
</div>
```

Comment: tried... the embedded tweets are still clickable :-( https://sane.social/testing.php?account=EladRatson

Answer (score 1):

The code below seems to work using your "twitter-tweet" class rather than the div to specify pointer events:

```
<head>
<style>
.twitter-tweet{
pointer-events: none;
}
</style>

</head>

<body>
<div class="right" style="display:inline-block;float:left;z-index:2">
  <blockquote class="twitter-tweet">
    <p lang="en" dir="ltr">Or hey, ya know, just relax and have fun. <a href="https://twitter.com/U53iZEL9O9">https://twitter.com/U53iZEL9O9</a></p>&mdash; Meg Turney (@megturney) <a href="https://twitter.com/megturney/status/1230141853246402560?ref_src=twsrc%5Etfw">February 19, 2020</a></blockquote>
  <script async src="https://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
</div>
</body>
```

However, when I run the code you've posted, it behaves as specified as well. It seems you may have other code preventing your efforts here. Nonetheless try adding pointer-events: none; to your twitter-tweet class instead.

Comment: "it works" is never an answer. At best it's a comment

Comment: The post outlines modifications to the current code which may yield the desired result. A bit more than "it works".

Comment: i don't have a class .twitter-tweet in my stylesheet... I think this class is loaded by Twitter's widget.js as part of the embed...?

Comment: try adding the class to the head of your page. Should inherit previous style from widget.js and apply forward your pointer-events: none;