# disable click on div element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I've been trying for a good while to try and disable a click on a div.

The reason behind this is to stop unauthorised users from triggering events etc which are activated when a user clicks on a div. From my attempt below i tried a click false but it doesnt seem to work, maybe im not using the correct syntax to disable the div?

```
$('#content2').on('click', false);
```

update:

here is the complete code involved

View

```
    <h2>Notifications & Updates</h2>

    <p id="content2" contenteditable"true" ></p>

    <button id="save">Save Changes</button>

</div>

<div id="Section2"></div>

@*Scripts go at end for the contenteditable div to load correctly*@
<script type="text/javascript" src="~/Scripts/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="~/Scripts/editable.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="~/Scripts/EditContentHome.js"></script>

@if (User.Identity.Name == "WORKER")
{
    <script type="text/javascript" src="~/Scripts/SecurityEditHide.js"></script>
}
```

SecurityEditHide.JS

```
window.onload = function () {
$('textarea').prop('disabled', true);

$('#content2').on('click', false);
$('#content2').prop('contenteditable', false);
$('#save').hide();
};
```

EditContentHome.JS

```
    $("#content2").click(function () {
    $("#save").show(1000);

});

$("#save").click(function () {
    $("#save").hide(1000);

});
```

Comment: *"...it doesnt seem to work..."* How? What are you seeing that makes you think it's not working? Works here: http://jsfiddle.net/fgqrc4kv/

Comment: You need to wrap the click functionality in a conditional tag that checks whether the user is authorized or not, if they're not authorized clicking the div will do nothing.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5259191/disable-clicking-of-a-divs-element?rq=1 and perhaps you should consider not binding the click event in the first place until the user is authorized? Also, I should advise you not to rely on this for security purposes as users can modify the js on your page.

Comment: Are the events on the div or are they inside the div on other elements? Why are the events attached in the first place if the user is not authorized?

Comment: @epascarello i basically have a content editable div, when a user clicks on it the it shows the edit button etc, now when a user logs in that isnt admin, the contenteditable div should be disabled to stop them from changing the html text, its not a huge security risk, the contenteditable is basically a message from admin to workers on the factory floor

Comment: Are you sure that the div exists at the time of `window.onload`?

Comment: @goldeneye `$('#content2').prop('contenteditable', false);` should work as expected then. But you'd have better to provide sample replicating your issue as code snippet/jsFiddle

Comment: @Jacob yes it does exist at the time

Comment: @goldeneye: Perhaps you can create an [MCVE](/help/mcve) demonstrating the problem, on first glance the code above seems fine for what you describe.

Comment: I've updated the question with all relevant code linked to the contenteditable issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change

```
$('#content2').on('click', false);
```

to

```
$('#content2').off('click');
```

That *removes* the click handler that you've set up in your earlier script. (Example below.)

Your `$('#content2').on('click', false);` didn't work because all it did was attach a second handler to the element that prevented the default action and stopped propagation. But those don't do anything to prevent other handlers for the **same** element getting called. (There is [`stopImmediatePropagation`](http://api.jquery.com/event.stopImmediatePropagation/), which does, but you're really better off just removing the handler entirely in this case.)

Live example:

```html
<h2>Notifications & Updates</h2>

<p id="content2" contenteditable="true">Presumably some text here</p>

<button id="save">Save Changes</button>

</div>

<div id="Section2"></div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
// From EditContentHome.JS:
$("#content2").click(function () {
    $("#save").show(1000);
});
</script>
<script>
// From SecurityEditHide.JS:
window.onload = function () {
    $('textarea').prop('disabled', true);

    $('#content2').off('click'); // <==== Change is here
    $('#content2').prop('contenteditable', false);
    $('#save').hide();
};
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks T.J ! i appreciate the help! thanks for explaining stopImmediatePropagation as well

Answer (score -1):

Naturally divs are not clickable except you attach an onclick event to them , however you can do this

```
.enable{
    //indicate your preferred color  
    background-color: blue;
     cursor : pointer ;

  }

 .disable{
  background-color: grey;
   cursor:none ;
  }
```

You can then check for user authorization when a click is done if authorized apply the right css using jquery.removeClass().addClass('enable') else jquery.removeClass().addClass('disable').